# ループ中にbreakでループを抜けられません

Tags: c++, string

[一週間で身につくC++言語の基本](https://cpp-lang.sevendays-study.com/) というサイトの応用編の問題「4日目 STL」のページの、「probex4-4」という問題に取り組んでいます。コードの目的としては、文字列を配列に格納するループの中で何も入力せずエンターしたところでループを抜け次の処理に入るというものです。

元々while文で書いていたのですが、無限ループに入ってしまい強制終了してから取り敢えずfor文で簡易的に試しています。実際、挙動としては何も入力せずにエンターを押した後にbreakしてくれません。おそらくif文の条件が問題だと思うのですが、string型で「何も入力していない状態」がどのような状態なのかがうまく書けません。

とても初歩的なことだと思いますが、どなたかご教授お願いします。

**環境:**
g++ 9.4.0
WSL2 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str = "a";
    vector<string> v1;
    vector<string>::iterator i1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "入力";
        cin >> str;
        string s_str = str;
        if (s_str.empty())
        {
            cout << "無し";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            v1.push_back(str);
        }
    }

    for (i1 = v1.begin(); i1 != v1.end(); i1++)
    {
        cout << *i1 << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そもそも

```
cin >> str;
```

は１文字以上入力されるまで終了することはなく、プログラムは次の行にも進みません。つまり

```
cin >> str;
string s_str = str;
if (s_str.empty())
```

が次の行に進んでいる時点で、 `str` および `s_str` は空でなく、 `s_str.empty()` は `false` を返します。

というわけで

> ループ中にbreakでループを抜けられません

ループを抜けられないのではなく、そもそも`break`が書かれた行に到達することがありません。

---

「次の行にも進みません」という日本語が理解できていないようです。プログラムを次のように書き換えれば、何を言っているか理解できるでしょうか。

```
cin >> str;
cout << "read: " << str << endl; // この行を追加
string s_str = str;
if (s_str.empty())
```

これで、「何も入力せずにエンターを押した」だけでは次の行に進んでいないことを理解できるかと。

Comment: cinするのがstring型だとできないということでしょうか？

Comment: empty であることがあり得ないということです。

Comment: 質問には書いていませんでしたが、.length()==0なども試したんですけどとりあえずそこを変えるべきということでしょうか？

Comment: それとも/nか何かがあるから0ではないということでしょうか？

Comment: @sukeryo 文字があるとかないとかそういう問題ではありません。回答を加筆しましたので、読み返してください。

Comment: 文字を入力しない限り次の行に進まないから、emptyであることがあり得ないということでしょうか？

Comment: getline()を使って解決できました。